# android art genertate verification errors,how to

Tags: android, jvm, dalvik

I want test function of art verification .
So,I want Create intentionally triggering code for ART virtual machine verification errors,how to do it
The relevant code for the verification logic is as follows

```
insn_flags_.reset(new InstructionFlags[code_item_->insns_size_in_code_units_]());
// Run through the instructions and see if the width checks out.
bool result = ComputeWidthsAndCountOps();
// Flag instructions guarded by a "try" block and check exception handlers.
result = result && ScanTryCatchBlocks();
// Perform static instruction verification.
result = result && VerifyInstructions();
// Perform code-flow analysis and return.
result = result && VerifyCodeFlow();
// Compute information for compiler.
if (result && Runtime::Current()->IsCompiler()) {
  result = Runtime::Current()->GetCompilerCallbacks()->MethodVerified(this);
}
```

Here is some relevant information I was able to gather

[Android - Verification failed on class ART / Dalvik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083729/android-verification-failed-on-class-art-dalvik)

[How to Generate INVOKE-POLYMORPHIC opcodes in Dalvik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027506/how-to-generate-invoke-polymorphic-opcodes-in-dalvik)

Comment: run it by dalvikvm32 can produce this error;
VerifyClass rick TooFewArguments
 Verifier rejected class TooFewArguments: void TooFewArguments.<init>() failed to verify: 
 void TooFewArguments.<init>(): [0xB] void TooFewArguments.<init>(): [0xB] Rejecting invocation,

but run it direct like user,

got another type


java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(MethodHandleNotInvoke,String,int[])void to (String)void